# Error on when doing npm install, ENOENT, lstat on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

I'm creating a project that manages blog posts (basically). I just recently installed this on a cloud platform, and no problems. I just wanted to clean up my `node_modules` folder so I deleted it and installed again with `npm install`.

Now, I can't install mongoose anymore, all the different modules are created fine. But the mongoose can not be installed. It's driving me crazy.

This is the error I get.

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.6.2
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/petur/Documents/WebProjects/soundMixes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/README.md
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "soundMixes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a webapp to manage soundmixes",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "mongoose" :"",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli" : "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-recess": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-targethtml" : "",
    "express" :"",
    "mongoose" : "",
    "formidable" : "",
    "body-parser" : ""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Does __sudo npm install__  work?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the most recent version of mongoose to install instead of leaving the version blank.

```
npm install --save mongoose
```

I'm also not sure why youre installing your packages as Dev dependencies when you'll need them for deployment.